# Databound WPF, Multipage Tiffs, Memory Streams and Performance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

I have a databound object within a WPF control that is 'previewing' a mutlipage tiff.

The object has a public PreviewImage, and CurrentPreviewPage.

It has a private PreviewPages which is a collection of MemoryStreams (each representing a page of the Tiff).

Upon the get of the PreviewImage (the first time) this code runs:

```
if (PreviewPages.Count == 0)
{
    Image myImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_LocalFile);

    for (int i = 0; i < (NumberOfPages); i++)
    {
        myImg.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, i);
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        myImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        PreviewPages.Add(ms);
    }
}
```

The previous code takes about 10 seconds to run for a 1100KB 17 page TIFF. There must be a better way of handling this.
Afterwards, this is called:

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 1000;
//bi.UriSource = new Uri(fiTemp.FullName);
bi.StreamSource = new System.IO.MemoryStream(PreviewPages[CurrentPreviewPage - 1].ToArray());
bi.EndInit();
_PreviewImage = bi;
```

Now, after the initialization this code works fantastically (it can change pages as fast as you can drag a bound slider). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: but why you load all 17 pages? User can see only one a page in a single moment, isn't it? Load them in sequence in queue in seorate thread, begining from the first one. Like, for example, Adobe Reader, Google Docs and others  do.

Comment: Load your first page on the primary thread and then additional pages in the background - see BackGroundWorker.  Only primary thread can access the UI.  On the BackGroundWorker you need to decide if you are going to get the pages 2-x one at a time or all at once.  The user cannot get to page 2 until you bring page 2 to the UI thread.

Comment: That's true, but I still end up with a problem for the first one, but maybe this is the best approach. I will see if anyone else has other comments and/or reservations.

Comment: Does System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_LocalFile) take much time?  Hopefully it reads them in one at a time.

Comment: No, it seems like saving the memory stream is what takes the time. I don't know if there is a better way to do that. I moved it to a background worker and it loads the pages asynchronously, and it seems to work fine. I still don't understand why it takes ~10 seconds with 100% cpu usage to load a single 1MB tiff into multiple memorystreams.

Comment: I agree.  A 1.1 MB tiff into 17 pages seems like it should be more like 1 second.  I would pull System.IO.MemoryStream ms out of the loop and just ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream() in the loop.  Same, just declare bi once.  Those are very small items.  Something strange is going on there.  I am wondering if it is doing a TIFF format conversion?  I added my comment as a solution in case it gets you whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your first page on the primary thread and then additional pages in the background - see BackGroundWorker. Only primary thread can access the UI. On the BackGroundWorker you need to decide if you are going to get the pages 2-x one at a time or all at once. The user cannot get to page 2 until you bring page 2 to the UI thread.   I would implement cancel.  If the user gives up you don't want to tie up CPU.

Comment: This is a answer that works fine. I'm still going to play around with the way I'm opening the file/memory streams to see if there is a faster way to access it.

Comment: I changed the guts of the process to use the RawFormat of the image object (hopefully forcing it not to convert it) and a single MemoryStream object with negligible affects. I'll leave it like this and build a better interface to show the user what is/isn't loaded yet. Thanks!